# Kusto query analysis based on Key-Value telemetry data - flatten dataset

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, telemetry, kusto-explorer

I have a kusto table containing telemetry data like the following:

| Timestamp | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:01 | Position | 87.3 |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:13 | Temperature | 10.2 |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:55 | Temperature | 10.4 |
| 2022-11-10 10:01:25 | Position | 81.3 |
| 2022-11-10 10:01:42 | Temperature | 12.2 |
| 2022-11-10 10:02:13 | Temperature | 12.8 |
| 2022-11-10 10:02:44 | Position | 74.3 |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:01 | Temperature | 18.6 |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:19 | Position | 87.3 |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:38 | Temperature | 10.6 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:00 | Temperature | 10.7 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:00 | Temperature | 10.1 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:25 | Position | 80.3 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:59 | Temperature | 12.6 |

I would like to perform some analysis where I calculate the average temperature in a certain area; in buckets of 5 minutes.
Therefore I would like to average all temperatures as of the latest position being sent until the position is updated:

I would like to have something as follows

| Timestamp | Area | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:00 | 1 | 10.4 |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:00 | 2 | 12,53 |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:00 | 3 | 18.6 |

I tried extinding the table with a Area & temperature column based on the key value:

| Timestamp | Key | Value | Area | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:01 | Position | 87.3 | 1 |  |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:13 | Temperature | 10.2 |  | 10.2 |
| 2022-11-10 10:00:55 | Temperature | 10.4 |  | 10.4 |
| 2022-11-10 10:01:25 | Position | 81.3 | 2 |  |
| 2022-11-10 10:01:42 | Temperature | 12.2 |  | 12.2 |
| 2022-11-10 10:02:13 | Temperature | 12.8 |  | 12.8 |
| 2022-11-10 10:02:44 | Position | 74.3 | 3 |  |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:01 | Temperature | 18.6 |  | 18.6 |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:19 | Position | 87.3 | 1 |  |
| 2022-11-10 10:03:38 | Temperature | 10.6 |  | 10.6 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:00 | Temperature | 10.7 |  | 10.7 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:00 | Temperature | 10.1 |  | 10.1 |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:25 | Position | 80.3 | 2 |  |
| 2022-11-10 10:04:59 | Temperature | 12.6 |  | 12.6 |

I then tried to fill up the null values with the previous non-null value found followed by an aggregation, however the prev() function does not allow to find previous non-null values.

Currently I do not have any idea on how to achieve my goal.

Comment: There is no "Area" in your sample data. Where did it pop out from? What are the required results? What is the transformation logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scan operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator) for analyzing sequences. Here is a possible solution, but without the Area code and with 4 distinct positions.

```
datatable (Timestamp: datetime, Key: string, Value: real) [
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:00:01), "Position", 87.3,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:00:13), "Temperature", 10.2,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:00:55), "Temperature", 10.4,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:01:25), "Position", 81.3,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:01:42), "Temperature", 12.2,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:02:13), "Temperature", 12.8,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:02:44), "Position", 74.3,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:03:01), "Temperature", 18.6,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:03:19), "Position", 87.3,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:03:38), "Temperature", 10.6,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:04:00), "Temperature", 10.7,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:04:00), "Temperature", 10.1,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:04:25), "Position", 80.3,
    datetime(2022-11-10 10:04:59), "Temperature", 12.6,
]
| sort by Timestamp asc
| scan declare (Position: real) with (
    step Pos output= none: Key == "Position";
    step Temp: Key == "Temperature" => Position= Pos.Value;
)
| summarize round(avg(Value), 2) by Position
```

Result:

| Position | avg_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 87.3 | 10.4 |
| 81.3 | 12.5 |
| 74.3 | 18.6 |
| 80.3 | 12.6 |